# Differentiating between distributions via fit

Tags: normal-distribution, goodness-of-fit, laplace-distribution

I have two experimental data sets: (a) one is theoretically distributed as a Laplace distribution and the other (b) is theoretically distributed as a Gaussian distribution.

I've fit the data (a and b) to their respective curves, but I'd like to say that it's reasonable to assume (b) is not actually Laplacian distributed and (a) is not actually Gaussian distributed.

What is a good metric for this?

I'm currently using the sum of squares of the residual between the data and fit--it shows that the I'm more accurate in using the expected distributions, but is this the best (or good enough) metric?